# Надо синонимизировать метки на тему [colab]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо синонимизировать метки:

- [colab](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colab) (14 вопросов)
- [google-colaboratory](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-colaboratory) (15 вопросов)

Я конечно понимаю что я и сам смогу их вырезать где надо, но хочется чтобы новые вопросы с этой меткой сразу изменялись.

Итак предлагаю синонимизировать эти метки в сторону [google-colaboratory](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-colaboratory) (более понятное название, есть описание и по ней больше вопросов)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 17 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 14 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 12 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'colab': [colab] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 27
tag remapping of [google-colaboratory] and [colab] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym colab -> google-colaboratory was approved!
```